# I accidentally purged python2.7, can you help me restore?

Tags: apt

On Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity) I accidentally did `apt-get purge python2.7 python-pip python-dev` (I wasn't aware of the fact that python 2.7 is used by so many important apps.

After getting a small heart attack and reading online that I could end up with a very stripped down Ubuntu, I was actually surprised that everything looked the same. Even after a reboot.
Now I notice some things actually not working anymore, like the Samba client with Nautilus for example.

Can you help me restore everything that got removed? I extracted this list of packages from `/var/log/apt/history.log`:

https://pastebin.com/4W5dRUAw

Should I just extract the raw package names and feed them through apt-get install or do the right packages have to be installed to reference to the dependancies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu 16.04 reinstall python2.7 and all of the purged packages that depends on python2.7. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-all
sudo reboot
sudo apt install python-wnck python-gnome2 python-six libgcj16 python-tdb python2.7-dev python-pymysql vprerex python-vte gvfs-backends python-samba steam-launcher python-xdg vlc-plugin-samba python-markupsafe python-pycurl python-zmq libcairo2-dev python-dnspython python-keybinder python-gi samba samba-dsdb-modules libatspi2.0-dev python-dbus python2.7 python-appindicator jackd2 texlive-lang-indic python-cairo python-chardet python-gobject python-notify texlive-pictures prosper libsdl2-dev python python-lxml guake python-pexpect texlive-xetex texlive-latex-extra python-talloc samba-libs python-crypto libpango1.0-dev gcj-5-jre-lib gimp texlive-music m64py python-ptyprocess python-jinja2 prerex texlive-full libgtk-3-dev arronax libjack-jackd2-0 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 python-pkg-resources libpulse-dev python-html5lib python-all python-apt inkscape samba-vfs-modules libglib2.0-dev python-bs4 arronax-base texlive-pstricks hamster-applet python-dev python-pyorbit zenmap python-setuptools libsmbclient libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev samba-common-bin libasound2-plugins:i386 hamster-indicator python-gtk2 pdftk python-decorator texlive-formats-extra ipython python-gconf jackd2-firewire python-wheel texlive-science ndiff python-ldb python-gobject-2 python-glade2 libgcj-common python-nautilus libatk1.0-dev libatk-bridge2.0-dev python-numpy python-tornado python-pip python-simplegeneric arronax-nautilus python-all-dev ipython-notebook
```

In Ubuntu 18.04 these commands would not work because 11 of the packages in the 3rd command are no longer available from the default Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Thank you, that already looks very promising! What I wanted to aim for with my last question was: Are these packages being marked as manually installed by reinstalling them this way? Is that a problem when I want to remove them later?

Can you also show the commands you used to get the packages from my list formatted so nicely? That would be great!

Comment: Yes, the packages are marked as manually installed by reinstalling them this way, and that will not be a problem if you want to remove them later because the packages are installed in exactly the same way either way, To format the package list I replaced the beginning and ending characters of the strings to be removed by < and > characters in Gedit and then pasted the entire string back into my answer enclosed by `<pre>` at the beginning and `</pre>` at the end. This converts the entire string into **pre**formatted text which does not show any text between each pair of the < and > characters.

Comment: Another way to do the same thing in the terminal with a one-liner command is: `sed -e s/:amd64\ [^,]*,//g input.txt` where input.txt contains the original unformatted text.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! That was very helpful. My system seems to be repaired.